# Log4j2 configuration of library

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have the following application structure.

1- Outer app which is executed directly via console. It's log4j configuration is provided via log4j2.configurationFile property.

2- Inner apps which is executed through ProcessBuilder. They are also configured the same way as outer app.

The problem is outer applications configuration file overrides inner ones'. So, every application takes the outer app's log4j2 configuration file. In inner applications, using LoggerContext, it works but there are restrictions preventing me to change inner applications. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a different environment property for the sub-process via the `ProcessBuilder` before you launch:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = // whatever you use now

pb.environment().put("log4j2.configurationFile", otherLog4JPropFile);
 
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: I am doing this ,but this does not work. Configuration over LoggerContext overrides the one through property.

Comment: You should update you question with details of what you have tried, it may help others find a solution.